# no automatic DNSSEC key rollover

Tags: bind, dnssec

I have a DNSSEC `bind` server. Everything works just fine - except one little issue: Why there is no automatic ZSK rollover happening?

I thought the bind will generate and install new ZSK keys every 180 days. Are my expectations incorrect or are there problems with my config? I did not found any hints in the logs. How can I debug it?

I'm currently running version 9.18.24:

The policy in `/etc/named.conf`:

```
dnssec-policy "my_policy" {
    keys {
        ksk key-directory lifetime unlimited algorithm ecdsa256;
        zsk key-directory lifetime P180D algorithm ecdsa256;
    };  
    nsec3param iterations 0 optout no salt-length 0;
    parent-ds-ttl PT1H;
};
```

and the output of `rndc dnssec -status ....`. (Why is *"No rollover scheduled"*?)

```
key: 51503 (ECDSAP256SHA256), ZSK
  published:      yes - since Fri Dec  9 12:11:44 2022
  zone signing:   yes - since Fri Dec  9 12:11:44 2022

  No rollover scheduled
  - goal:           omnipresent
  - dnskey:         omnipresent
  - zone rrsig:     omnipresent
```